# How can I show that there is a polynomial $Q(x)$ such that $P(x)=x(x+1)(2x+1)Q(x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Given that $P(x)=(x+1)^{2n}-x^{2n} -2x-1$   $(n>2)$.How can I show that there is a polynomial $Q(x)$ such that $P(x)=x(x+1)(2x+1)Q(x)$?

I really don't know how and from what I have to start with :/ In this exercise ... do we need to find $Q(x)$ ?

Can someone help me ? Thanks

Comment: Use little Bézout's theorem: show, that $0$, $-1$ and $-\frac12$ are roots of $P(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Remember the [factor theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem): if $a$ is a root of $P(x)$, then $P(x)$ is divisible by $(x-a)$ (i.e. has it as a factor.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $x-a$ divides a polynomial $P(x)$ if and only if $P(a)=0$. Since $P(0) = 1^{2n}-1=0$, we must have $P(x) = xP_2(x)$ for some polynomial $P_2$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yeah thank u then how I can found Q(x) ? is it necessery ?

Comment: No you don't need to find $Q(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Show that $x = 0,-1,-1/2$ are all roots of your polynomial $P(x)$. Then by theorem, you will have that $x(x+1)(2x+1)$ is a factor of your polynomial $P(x)$, because every polynomial can be written as a product of linear factors in terms of the (possibly complex number) roots, i.e. $P(x) = (x - c_1)(x - c_2) \cdots (x - c_{2n})$ where the $c_i$ are complex number roots of your polynomial, i.e. solutions to $P(x) = 0$.